# Most beautiful way of chaining a list of functions in python/numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a list of numpy functions

```py
fcts = [lambda x : np.power(x,2),np.sqrt,lambda x : np.add(x,3.)]
```

that I want to apply to an input `x` by chaining, i.e.

```
np.power(np.sqrt(np.add(x,3.)),2)
```

(or the other way around)

Is there an intrinsic numpy function for that or what is the most elegant/fastest way to do that (for a large list of functions) instead of

```
input = np.random.uniform(0,1,(2,3))
for fct in fcts:
    input = fct(input)
```

---

Edit:
Numpy is written in C++ and I am wondering, wether there is any 'loss in speed' when the results are converted to python between the functions (and assigned to the variable `input`).

Comment: `python/numpy` does not use C++.  Most of the underlying code is `c`.  But your code is interpreted.  As for the relative speed, you'll have to do your testing.

Comment: Each function call returns a Python object (e.g. a `numpy` array), regardless of the calling method.  Assigning it to the `input` variable is a minor step.

Answer (score 2):

Here, `reduce()` from the `functools` module can do the trick, although I believe the underlying behaviour is pretty close to what you did.

```
import functools
functools.reduce(lambda o, func: func(o), fcts , input_object)
```

Comment: Thanks, I know that numpy is written in C++ and I was wondering, wether there is any 'loss in speed' when the results are converted to python between the functions.